# excel formula-return latest entry based on lookup in date range

Tags: excel-formula

| date | rate |
| --- | --- |
| 01/1/23 | 3% |
| 8/1/23 | 5% |
| 10/1/23 | 7% |

above is my reference table for rates.  I want to use this as a lookup table.

Then on another sheet I have a long table with each row has a date.  based on that date I want to reference the above table, and return the rate if it is on of after that day.

so for example, something with a date of 2/1/23 should return 3%.  something with a date of 12/21/23 should return 7%.

any help would be greatly appreciated!
thanks!

this seems to be working...

```
=VLOOKUP(A389,TbillRates!$I$7:$J$18,2,1)
```

Comment: sort your data on the date ascending then you can use a standard VLOOKUP.

Comment: hi @ScottCraner, above seems to be working.  you believe it will work all the time? (if sorted)

Comment: My crystal ball only works on seeing the past and then only muddily.  If your data is always sorted on the date is should always work.  It is what VLOOKUP was designed for.